# Why does doctrine use WHERE IN instead of LIMIT?

Tags: php, doctrine-1.2, doctrine

Why does doctrine (1.2) use `WHERE IN` instead of `LIMIT`?

This code:

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
   ->from('Table t')
   ->limit(10)
   ->getSqlQuery();
```

Returns something like this:

```
SELECT t.id_table AS t__id_table FROM table AS t WHERE t__id_table IN (1,2,3,4,10,12,18,20,21,25);
```

Instead of this:

```
SELECT t.id_table AS t__id_table FROM table AS t LIMIT 10;
```

This behaivor is same for any `LIMIT` value. This generates a very long queries for high `LIMIT` values.

Bonus question: How does Doctrine know, what ids to use? (By sending another query to DB??)

Comment: What database backend are you using?

Comment: Odd; I've just done something similar with Symfony 1.4's Doctrine, which I _think_ is version 1.2.3, and it uses the LIMIT clause for MySQL, as you'd expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `LIMIT` operates on database rows not "objects". When you type `$q->limit(10)` you want to get ten objects, not ten rows from database.

Consider following query (products and categories have many-to-many relationship):

```
SELECT p.*, c.* FROM product p 
INNER JOIN product_category_ref pcr ON p.id = pcr.prodcut_id
INNER JOIN category c ON c.id = pcr.category_id
WHERE p.price < 123;
```

To fetch 10 products (objects) your query will have to fetch at least 20 rows. You cannot use `LIMIT 10` cause (just for example) only 3 products would be returned. That's why you need to find out which products should be fetched (limit applies to products), and later fetch the actual data.

That will result in following queries:

```
SELECT p.id FROM product p WHERE p.price < 123;
SELECT ..... WHERE p.id IN (...);
```

Second query might return 20, 423 or 31 rows. As you can see that's not a value from `limit()`.

PS. Doctrine2 is much more clearer in that case as it's using `setMaxResults()` method instead of `limit()` which is less confusing.

Comment: where do you get this info from? according to manual limit() is part of DQL and is used before hydration

Comment: I know that from my own expierence and study of sources. And yes, you're right - `LIMIT` is part of DQL (`limit()` method comes from `QueryBuilder`) and as you can see it's used before hydration (the second query (the one which is actually hydrated) doesn't even have `LIMIT` clause)).

Comment: This sounds strange to me. I (and my collegues) thought the LIMIT is applied to the number of rows which is returned by the query (after process all joins, subqueries etc.).

Comment: SQL `LIMIT` limits the number of returned rows. DQL `LIMIT` limits the number of returned *hydrated* objects (and fetching 10 objects might require 10, 20, 30, 312 rows if some query contains joins).

Comment: There seem to be alot of confusion about how this works, and you're all right in a way, but allow me to explain how this works in Doctrine :) First, it has nothing to do with the hydration in any way and the `DQL LIMIT` does NOT translate to a `SQL LIMIT`. As said before, `SQL LIMIT` simply limits the amount of rows returned. So to furthermore combat the `impedance mismatch`, a `DISTINCT` query is first executed with a `SQL LIMIT` thats double the `DQL LIMIT`; then the ids are used in the main query in a `IN()` to virtually limit the amount of rows that must be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Using Doctrine 1.2.3:

```
<?php

include(dirname(__FILE__).'/Doctrine.php');
spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'));

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1', 'testdb', 'testdb');
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection($dbh);

class Table extends Doctrine_Record {
  public function setTableDefinition() {
    $this->hasColumn('id_table', integer, 10, array('primary' => true));
  }
}

$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
   ->from('Table t')
   ->limit(10)
   ->getSqlQuery();

echo $q;
```

I get the result:

```
SELECT t.id_table AS t__id_table FROM table t LIMIT 10
```

Is there maybe something else going on in your code?

Comment: We just got know that WHERE IN is used only when using JOIN. Sorry for confusing.